# Swagger UI POST - How to allow for newline character input?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui

For the life of me, I can't figure this one out.

I have a very simple ASP.NET Core WebAPI method as follows:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public int LineCount(string text)
    {
        var lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
        return lines.Length;
    }
```

and I paste in some text in the Swagger UI,

```
Help
me!
```

but I get a response of only one line.

**~~Why is the newline character being converted to a space?~~** (I've even checked with a breakpoint on the server, and sure enough it's a space character, not the newline character.)

> ***EDIT*:** Ok, I know now why it's converted to a space - because the HTML element is an `<input>`, but **how can I tell Swagger that I want a textarea** to allow newlines in the string?

[image: notepad source and text input]

When I check the Request Headers info in the dev tools, I can see that I have the HTML code for a space (`%20`).

[image: dev tools]

Comment: You can try customizing Swagger UI to use a multiline text field for that parameters - see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4278#issuecomment-370180502. Maybe this help with sending and auto-encoding multi-line values from Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the copied text on the url parameter, the default is string type.

If you want our backend code can recognize multiple lines of text. You need use `%0D%0A`.

[image]

## Reason

When your httprequest send to backend, it will urlencode params, so we can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode(Environment.NewLine)` to learn the format of `Environment.NewLine` in url.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[HttpPost]
public int LineCount(string text)
{
    text = WebUtility.UrlDecode(text);
    string ur = WebUtility.UrlEncode(Environment.NewLine);
    var lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    return lines.Length;
}
```